# SQL Logic: Need the row with the greatest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

OK, I have the following query that builds a table of a set of customers who used a product off of their account during a period. The report than uses that table to see which customers have not used a product off of their account in the second time period.

My issue is that for people who have used a product off of their account may have done so multiple times in that period. Therefore, when I pull back the data from the report for members who used a product in period one and not in period two, I am getting multiple rows because they used products multiple times.

I only need the latest/greatest date of usage row and not the other rows. I tried using MAX(SSUSED_1.usedate) but I am noting getting what I want. Any help would be appreciated!

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        SS.memid
    FROM SS
    INNER JOIN SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid
    INNER JOIN MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid
    INNER JOIN PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid
    INNER JOIN PRODUCTCATS ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES ON SSUSED.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
    WHERE
        MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite
        AND SSUSED.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek2 AND @rvEndWeek2
        AND PRODUCTS.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 61, 31, 32, 47))

SELECT DISTINCT 
    SS_1.memid,
    MEMBERS_1.scancode,
    MEMBERS_1.lname,
    MEMBERS_1.fname,
    PRODUCTS_1.description,
    EMPLOYEES_1.lname AS TrainLName,
    EMPLOYEES_1.fname AS TrainFName,
    SSUSED_1.usedate,
    SSUSED_1.transactiontype
FROM SS AS SS_1
INNER JOIN SSUSED AS SSUSED_1 ON SS_1.ssid = SSUSED_1.ssid
INNER JOIN MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS_1.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS AS PRODUCTS_1 ON SS_1.productid = PRODUCTS_1.productid
INNER JOIN PRODUCTCATS AS PRODUCTCATS_1 ON PRODUCTS_1.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS_1.productcatid
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES AS EMPLOYEES_1 ON SSUSED_1.employeeid = EMPLOYEES_1.employeeid
WHERE
    MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite
    AND SSUSED_1.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek1 AND @rvEndWeek1
    AND PRODUCTS_1.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 61, 31, 32, 47)
    AND NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT
            1 AS Expr1
        FROM cte AS cte_1
        WHERE SS_1.memid = memid)
ORDER BY TrainLName, MEMBERS_1.scancode, SSUSED_1.usedate DESC
```

Comment: I suggest simplifying your example that is a lot of joins for us to try and work through.  you should be able to get to your answer a few ways.  including using ROW_NUMBER window function, or using conditional aggregation you can probably do BOTH your queries in 1 step.  To make it clear what you want I would put some sample data together and expected result based on that data

Comment: The example here isn't really all that huge...but the formatting makes me want to take my eyeballs and peel them. Your code would be a lot easier for you (and others) to maintain if you took some time to make it legible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following might work?

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT        SS.memid
                             FROM            SS INNER JOIN
                                                      SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid INNER JOIN
                                                      MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid INNER JOIN
                                                      PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid INNER JOIN
                                                      PRODUCTCATS ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid INNER JOIN
                                                      EMPLOYEES ON SSUSED.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
                             WHERE        (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite) AND (SSUSED.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek2 AND @rvEndWeek2) AND (PRODUCTS.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 
                                                      58, 77, 75, 30, 61, 31, 32, 47)))
    SELECT -- DISTINCT 
                              SS_1.memid, MEMBERS_1.scancode, MEMBERS_1.lname, MEMBERS_1.fname, PRODUCTS_1.description, EMPLOYEES_1.lname AS TrainLName, 
                              EMPLOYEES_1.fname AS TrainFName, SSUSED_1.usedate, SSUSED_1.transactiontype
     FROM            SS AS SS_1 INNER JOIN
                              SSUSED AS SSUSED_1 ON SS_1.ssid = SSUSED_1.ssid INNER JOIN
                              MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS_1.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid INNER JOIN
                              PRODUCTS AS PRODUCTS_1 ON SS_1.productid = PRODUCTS_1.productid INNER JOIN
                              PRODUCTCATS AS PRODUCTCATS_1 ON PRODUCTS_1.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS_1.productcatid INNER JOIN
                              EMPLOYEES AS EMPLOYEES_1 ON SSUSED_1.employeeid = EMPLOYEES_1.employeeid
     WHERE        (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite) AND (SSUSED_1.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek1 AND @rvEndWeek1) AND (PRODUCTS_1.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 
                              75, 30, 61, 31, 32, 47)) AND (NOT EXISTS
                                  (SELECT        1 AS Expr1
                                    FROM            cte AS cte_1
                                    WHERE        (SS_1.memid = memid)))
     -- added below
     GROUP BY SS_1.memid, MEMBERS_1.scancode, MEMBERS_1.lname, MEMBERS_1.fname, PRODUCTS_1.description, EMPLOYEES_1.lname AS TrainLName, 
              EMPLOYEES_1.fname AS TrainFName, SSUSED_1.transactiontype HAVING MAX(SSUSED_1.usedate) = SSUSED_1.usedate
     ORDER BY TrainLName, MEMBERS_1.scancode, SSUSED_1.usedate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified line 4 to add as a column in CTE

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SS.memid ORDER BY SSUSED.usedate) AS RowNumber
```

I added to the NOT EXISTS statement

```
AND cte_1.RowNumber = 1
```

This resulted in:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        SS.memid,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SS.memid ORDER BY SSUSED.usedate) AS RowNumber
    FROM SS
    INNER JOIN SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid
    INNER JOIN MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid
    INNER JOIN PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid
    INNER JOIN PRODUCTCATS ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES ON SSUSED.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
    WHERE
        MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite
        AND SSUSED.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek2 AND @rvEndWeek2
        AND PRODUCTS.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 61, 31, 32, 47))

SELECT DISTINCT 
    SS_1.memid,
    MEMBERS_1.scancode,
    MEMBERS_1.lname,
    MEMBERS_1.fname,
    PRODUCTS_1.description,
    EMPLOYEES_1.lname AS TrainLName,
    EMPLOYEES_1.fname AS TrainFName,
    SSUSED_1.usedate,
    SSUSED_1.transactiontype
FROM SS AS SS_1
INNER JOIN SSUSED AS SSUSED_1 ON SS_1.ssid = SSUSED_1.ssid
INNER JOIN MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS_1.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS AS PRODUCTS_1 ON SS_1.productid = PRODUCTS_1.productid
INNER JOIN PRODUCTCATS AS PRODUCTCATS_1 ON PRODUCTS_1.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS_1.productcatid
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES AS EMPLOYEES_1 ON SSUSED_1.employeeid = EMPLOYEES_1.employeeid
WHERE
    MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite
    AND SSUSED_1.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek1 AND @rvEndWeek1
    AND PRODUCTS_1.productcatid IN (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 61, 31, 32, 47)
    AND NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT
            1 AS Expr1
        FROM cte AS cte_1
        WHERE SS_1.memid = memid
        AND cte_1.RowNumber = 1)
ORDER BY TrainLName, MEMBERS_1.scancode, SSUSED_1.usedate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions (`COUNT OVER`, `ROW_NUMBER OVER`) to find the `SSUSED` records you are interested in.

```
select
  ss.memid, 
  m.scancode, 
  m.lname, 
  m.fname, 
  p.description, 
  e.lname as trainlname, 
  e.fname as trainfname, 
  ssu.usedate, 
  ssu.transactiontype
from ss
join
(
  select 
    ssid,
    usedate, 
    transactiontype,
    count(case when usedate between @rvstartweek1 and @rvendweek1 then 1 end)
        over (partition by ssid) as count_period1,
    count(case when usedate between @rvstartweek2 and @rvendweek2 then 1 end)
        over (partition by ssid) as count_period2,
    row_number()
        over (partition by ssid order by usedate desc) as rn
  from ssused
) ssu on  ssu.ssid = ss.ssid 
      and ssu.count_period1 > 0
      and ssu.count_period2 = 0
      and ssu.rn = 1 
join members m as m on m.memid = ss.memid 
join products p as p on p.productid = ss.productid 
join employees e as e on e.employeeid = ssu.employeeid
where m.siteid = @rvSite
and p.productcatid in (27, 28, 29, 58, 77, 75, 30, 61, 31, 32, 47);
```